# How to read floating point data from a table in EF6

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, double

I try to read data from database

```
  db.Table1.Load();
```

and get exception

```
Specified cast is not valid.
```

StackTrace:

```
   в System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.VerifyType(Int32 i, DbType typ)
   в System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.GetDouble(Int32 i)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ShapedBufferedDataRecord.ReadDoubl
e(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ShapedBufferedDataRecord.Initializ
e(DbDataReader reader, DbSpatialDataReader spatialDataReader, Type[] columnTypes
, Boolean[] nullableColumns)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ShapedBufferedDataRecord.Initializ
e(String providerManifestToken, DbProviderServices providerServices, DbDataReade
r reader, Type[] columnTypes, Boolean[] nullableColumns)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.BufferedDataReader.Initialize(Stri
ng providerManifestToken, DbProviderServices providerServices, Type[] columnType
s, Boolean[] nullableColumns)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[T
ResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClassb.<GetResult
s>b__a()
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`
1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, B
oolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClassb.<GetResult
s>b__9()
   в System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult]
(Func`1 operation)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMerg
eOption)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.I
Enumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
   в System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   в System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   в System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
   в System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.Load(IQueryable source)
```

other tables are loaded normally.

like

```
 db.Table2.Load(); // works just fine, all columns has type string
```

`Table1` has columns with the type`double` but the standard delimiter character in my culture is a comma.

I thought that this should help but does not work either

```
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture =
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```

I still getting the exception

or am I looking for the error is not where I need it?

Comment: why are you downvoting me?

Comment: Any time you say you “get exception” you have to include the [entire expection](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/), not just a word or two you picked out, and include [the code that throws the exception](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/). Also, “does not work” tells us nothing; what does it do? What did you expect it to do?

Comment: @DourHighArch thank you for feedback. That's a full exception message, I would provide more if I could. I wrote line which raise exception. Does not work mean that I still getting exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. I go to github and saw that [VerifyType](https://github.com/OpenDataSpace/System.Data.SQLite/blob/master/System.Data.SQLite/SQLiteDataReader.cs) method is independent of current culture:

```
case TypeAffinity.Double:
          if (typ == DbType.Single) return affinity;
          if (typ == DbType.Double) return affinity;
          if (typ == DbType.Decimal) return affinity;
          if (typ == DbType.DateTime) return affinity;
break;
```

I checked the type of columns in database (it wasn't created by me) and it was `text`. I fixed by setting types to `numeric`.

I hope it help someone too.